# MySQL. Populate table from results query where different number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an empty table with 12 columns (the first one is ID AUTO_INCREMENT).

This table I must populate directly from a query that gives me 8 columns.  Here is the query

```
INSERT INTO table_name
    SELECT t.one,
           ag.two AS two_name,
           a.three,
           a.four,
           t.five,
           s.six as six_name,
           s.seven as seven_name,
           s.eight as eight_name,
           '-',
           '-',
           '-'
    FROM table_t AS t
        JOIN table_st AS st ON t.trip_id = st.trip_id 
        JOIN table_s AS s ON s.s_id = st.a_id 
        JOIN table_a AS a ON a.a_id = t.a_id 
        JOIN agency_group AS ag ON ag.id = t.a_id
    WHERE 
        st.somefield = 1
    ORDER BY t.somefield ASC 
                     ;
```

And If I run this subquery alone (without `INSERT INTO table_name`) it works fine.

When I run it entirely like written above in order to input those results directly into table I got this error:

> 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

PS. All column types and names are matching.

Can someone please point with a finger where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: You can skip the ORDER BY, makes no difference.

Comment: I recommend you to use syntax like this: `INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2,...)` specify column names of target table.

Comment: Thanks Jarlh, actually it makes difference, because 't.somefield' is from another table than 'st.somefield'. I will edit this query a bit.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas how would you write it taking into account my task (populate table directly from another query)? Please do not suggest to run a query for each column. It is just unacceptable for a DB (10Gb)

Comment: You just need to specify all column names for target table as you do It with source table in `SELECT` clause. `INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2,...coln) SELECT col1, col2,...coln FROM....`

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas You have to write it in answer if you want me to accept it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always list the columns when you do an insert:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, . . ., coln)
    SELECT col1, col2, . . ., coln
    FROM . . .
```

The error message is pretty clear.  The table has more or fewer columns than the `SELECT`.

Comment: It is correct also like Stanislovas Kalašnikovas wrote this. But to be pretty clear please write your answer like ( INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2 ..., col8) SELECT col1,col2 ... , col8   ... )   because that is exactly why I had it wrong. I will accept it when it is edited. Thanks

Comment: @AlexRos - how exactly do you want this edited?  It seems like you are asking him to edit to the same as it already is.

Comment: @Hogan This answer is not precise. The precise answer is given by Stanislovas Kalašnikovas in comment here above. `INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2,...coln) SELECT col1, col2,...coln FROM....`

Comment: ah I see -- you are bothered by a lack of "coln"s, ok changed.